# Jquery: check if a form is already submitted and validated

Tags: jquery, magento2

I have a popup which contains a form and a submit button. On submit, the popup gets closed and the form is validated. I need to run some code after popup close, but the popup can be closed by the user without submitting the form.

I need to check on popup close that the form is submitted and validated, so I can run my custom code.

I am aware of `$('#formId').validate().checkForm()` but it validates even before submit button click.

```
$('#FormId').on('modalclosed', function() {
    //check if form is submitted and validated
    //custom code
});
```

Comment: How are you displaying and closing the popup?

Comment: I am using Magento 2 modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking if the form was submitted after closing, check if the form has been submitted and close it if the form is valid.

```
$('#FormId').on('submit', function() {

    //check if form is valid
    if ($('#FormId').validate()) {

        // form is valid, close modal
        $('#modalId').modal('closeModal');

        // custom code to run after form is submitted and valid

    }
});
```

The id's might need adjustment to work with your code